# Installing PIL on OSX Mountain Lion for google app engine,

Tags: python, installation, python-imaging-library, osx-mountain-lion

I know there are many questions on SO, and forum and blog posts around the web, but I keep running into the same problems. I'm trying to install PIL to use it for the app engine imaging api. In the [api overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/installingPIL#mac), google suggests installing it from [pythonmac.org](http://pythonmac.org/packages/py25-fat/index.html).

When I try to install the dmg provided there, it tells me that it requires python 2.5 to be installed as the system python. A little googling around for this error, pointed me to this SO question: [How to install PIL on Mac OSX 10.5.8 for Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868185/how-to-install-pil-on-mac-osx-10-5-8-for-google-app-engine). In the first answer for that, I did step 1, I installed macports. Then, step 2 told me to run `sudo port install python25`.

This gave me the following error:

```
Error: org.macports.activate for port expat returned: Image error: /opt/local/bin/xmlwf already exists and does not belong to a registered port.  Unable to activate port expat. Use 'port -f activate expat' to force the activation.
Error: Failed to install expat
Please see the log file for port expat for details:
/opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_textproc_expat/expat/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: gettext expat libiconv ncurses libedit openssl zlib python_select sqlite3
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port python25 failed
```

For the full output of macports, see [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/EPMxZFQ0)

When that didn't work out, a bit more googling brought me to [this blog post](http://www.janeriksolem.net/2012/09/installing-pil-on-os-x-mountain-lion.html). I installed libjpeg, as it suggests. The following steps it suggests are:

> 2. Download PIL from http://effbot.org/downloads/Imaging-1.1.7.tar.gz. (Remove PIL first if installed already.)
> 3. In the unpacked folder:
>      python setup.py build --force
>      sudo python setup.py install

But when I tried running python setup.py build --force, I got this error:

```
_imaging.c:3017: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
_imaging.c:3077: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/q_/wgr019b53rx9b2lr3y7867bm0000gn/T//ccJY6hPI.out
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

for the full output, check [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/KyGQchBu).

There are some other things I've tried, and I'll edit those in, but I want to get this posted asap.
thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is [Pillow](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/). The Plone folks got sick of exactly these types of headaches and forked PIL.

Pillow is a drop-in replacement for PIL that *isn't* a nightmare to build and install.